# Javascript: Search Array of Object and Get Linked Values From Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this array of object structured like below:

```
[   
    {name:"12345", zip: "90860", customerCategory: "loyal"}
    {name:"17625", zip: "93011", customerCategory: "new"}
    {name:"13545", zip: "90860", customerCategory: "visitor"}
]
```

When I search this with the javaScript `find` function for name as in:

```
const found = orderList.find(o => o.name === '12345');
```

The returned result is true; however, I am not sure how to access the values of a certain object when it is found. For example, if I search for **17625** and since it is found, how can I retrieve the other zip and customerCategory values for this particular object (Which would be zip: "93011" and customerCategory: "new" )

Comment: `found` refers to the object which matches the `name` property. As such you can use `found.zip` or `found.customerCategory`

Comment: Thank you. Just needed some guidance. This works!